# Asterisk: Using extension patterns with call files

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to make a script that makes call files for Asterisk to execute, however I want the extensions within the call files to match my extensions's patterns.

Call file:

```
Channel: trunk/10
Context: call-file
Extension: 123
Priority: 1
```

extensions.conf:

```
[call-file]
exten = _XXX,1,NoOp(it works)
```

123 should be able to be matched by _XXX, however it only works if I explicitly write 123 in my extensions.conf.
With the pattern I get the following error:

```
sent to invalid extension but no invalid handler: context,exten,priority=call-file,123,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, it first try call trunk/10.

You example works for me

```
Asterisk 1.8.32.2

[call-file]
exten = _XXX,1,NoOp(it works)
exten = _XXX,n,Wait(100)
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,2,Wait(10)


Channel: Local/s@call-file/n
Context: call-file
Extension: 123
Priority: 1
```

Result:

```
-- Executing [s@call-file:1] Answer("Local/s@call-file-00000000;2", "") in new stack
-- Executing [123@call-file:1] NoOp("Local/s@call-file-00000000;1", "it works") in new stack
-- Executing [123@call-file:2] Wait("Local/s@call-file-00000000;1", "100") in new stack
-- Remote UNIX connection
-- Executing [s@call-file:2] Wait("Local/s@call-file-00000000;2", "10") in new stack
```

Maybe it can't call trunk or you need update your asterisk.